# Query_vars not working for me

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to add an all pages link to posts when I have `?all=1` at the end of the URL it's returning "not set", I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked here and my code is the same as here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Custom_Archives

functions.php

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'all_pages' );
function all_pages( $qvars ) {
$qvars[] = 'all';
return $qvars;
}
```

single.php

```
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['all'])) {
    $remove_pagination = $wp_query->query_vars['all']; 
    echo "all set";

} else { echo "not set"; };
```

Comment: _When_ did you add the filter? On _which hook_?

Comment: @kaiser I'm not exactly sure what you mean, I'm not a programmer, just stumbling through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was with nginx, specifically:

```
location / {
   index index.php index.html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Which I changed `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` as outlined [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,172365,172365) which also fixed another issue that I was having with URL parameters.